# Apple distribute certificate for two apps, only working for one

Tags: ios, certificate, adobe-dps

I'm new to the IOS-developer world and at the moment I'm working on some Adobe DPS apps. Right now I'm stuck with this problem - I'm using the same Apple distribution certificate for two different apps but it seems to only be working for one of them, from my understanding I **can** (and should?) use the same distribution certificate for both of them, since I can't create any more distribution certificates for my team in Apple Dev (I am the Agent user). One of the apps works great but when I try to install the other one I get the error "Unable to download app". The apps are pretty much the same and for the broken app I've generated a new signed.ipa file, the App ID is correct in the .plist file and everything else seem to be correct too. What could possibly have caused this problem?

Comment: If you're getting "unable to download the app" maybe it's something with service that you're using to download the app. From where are you installing this app? Also try to recreate your provisioning profiles and regenerate app in App Builder with the new ones.

Answer (score 1):

Two apps should use two individual different app ids, but you can share the same wildcard distributions profile. For e.g., if your profile is com.abc.* then you can apply this distribution provision profile to all those app with this com.abc. prefix, like com.abc.a, .b .c whatever your app id created in itunesconnect.

But for App store distribution certificate, you should only have one.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply. In this case the app id:s are different.. Still have no idea what's causing the problem, I've double-checked that the correct files/id:s are included so many times now :(